# Jquery ajax contentType confused me

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using jquery ajax function.
I noticed an issue when I post JSON data to the server.

The type of post data is JSON.  So I added the code to specify what I sent was JSON.

```
contentType: "application/json".
```

I wrote below code:

```
var data = {"data": "mytestdata" };
var option = {
     url: 'Handler1.ashx',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function (result) {
         alert(result);
     },
     data: data,
     contentType: "application/json"
 };
 $.ajax(option);
```

At the server side, I used below code:

```
string s = context.Request["data"];
```

But the result `s` was `null`.

Logically,setting `contentType="application/json"` and posting json data are perfect. But it's false.

Also I tried code in php file:

```
echo $_POST["data"];
```

PHP says `$_POST["data"] doesn't exist`.

So I tried to remove the code -- `contentType: "application/json"`.

Now,everything is OK.

But it confused me.
 Why needn't set contentType as json when we post the real json data?

Comment: you don't post json, you post form-data. data will be encoded by jquery before the submission

Comment: You could set the option `processData` to false. Then the data would not be converted to a query string. And a query string has the default contentType of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: @redreggae: no, that doesn't work

Comment: @roast_soul if you do this then you cannot get the data with `POST` array. look at the answer from Rajat. But why you wanna do this?

Comment: so the best thing is you don't add the `contentType` option and then it should work..

Comment: @redreggae:I just want to make it more logically,send json data,and set content-type as json.

Comment: @roast_soul: but then you cannot use `context.Request["data"]`. Then you have to parse the request by yourself and decode the json. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398926/how-to-retrieve-json-via-asp-net-context-request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do `contentType: "application/json"`, when you don't specify content type, it converts the data to be sent in http params, from the json..which are accessible via $_GET, or $_POST params..

But if you want to send json data only..you can try this code on server side to get the data:

```
<?php
$data = @file_get_contents('php://input');
print_r(json_decode($data));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were not sending JSON data back.  jQuery considers it an error when the ajax content type is set to accept JSON, but malformed JSON is sent back.

`echo $_POST['data']` will likely throw the exception "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" -- so that actually gets printed out.  That's not valid JSON.

What you probably want to do is `echo json_encode($_POST['data']);`

Comment: `contentType` defines the type of data jQuery will send to the server. The expected type of the response will be defined by `dataType`.